# GCloud function call error: Error: could not handle the request

Tags: function, gcloud

I have billing enabled for my project, however, I keep on getting an error returned:

**Error: could not handle the request**

And the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage
import requests

def call(request):
    
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"

    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = response.json()
    pretty_json = json.dumps(json_data)

    print(pretty_json)
```

With requirements being:

```
requests
google.cloud.storage
```

Comment: `google.com` does not return JSON so the attempt to parse it using `.json()` raises an error. You can try using a test JSON endpoint instead of `http://www.google.com` perhaps `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`

Comment: Changed it - thanks. Still getting an error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

1. Create a virtualenv

```py
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

2. Install Requests (you're not using Google Cloud Storage)

```py
python3 -m pip install requests
```

3. Script

```py
import json
import requests

    
url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

4. Execute the code

```py
python3 main.py
```

5. Results

```
200
```

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. I am trying to do this inside GCloud Function and calling it with my cmd. The answer you gave does work when I work locally.

Comment: The code should work unchanged in a Cloud Function. You'll just need to wrap it in according to Google's Functions framework